# Adding callers to conference using asterisk agiphp

Tags: asterisk, agi

agiphp guru of stack flow

My question is

I'm developing an application where a junk of work is about making conference call.I want to write Agi preferably PHP based where user A holds DID using SIP trunk which is connected to asterisk server need to make conference call(outgoing) like calling B,C,D....n and puting them in conference.If there is any example please share or give ur valuable feedback to implement it. I'm currently using asterisk 1.8

but meet me and confbridge is not much of use for me as well as auto dial out.I need something like for example user A with exten 1234 calling user B with exten 5678 and both are in a call now user A or B need to call to user c with exten 1111 and try to call him and put all user A,B,C in one conference

Answer (score 1):

Please read this pages

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe

But note, dialout can have very tricky issues, so not recommended do dialout application if you are not expert.
For more info consider check opensource diallers like vicidial.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response,